# Spring Boot + Batch : Injected/Autowired beans are null in ItemReader

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I get a NPE when I try to Autowire any bean in the ItemReader. Can somebody please help me with where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

The requirement is I'd like to inject a DAO in the ItemReader to fetch data from multiple sources and create a single object.

This is the Config Class that I have -

```
    @Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ReportMetadataConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job fetchReportMetadataJob;

    @Bean
    public Job fetchReportMetadataJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("fetchReportMetadataJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener())
                .flow(reportWriterStep()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step reportWriterStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("reportWriterStep").<ReportMetadataDTO, ReportMetadataDTO> chunk(1)
                .reader(compositeItemReader())
                .processor(new ReportMetadataProcessor())
                .writer(reportMetadataWriter()).build();
    }

    public ItemReader<ReportMetadataDTO> compositeItemReader() {
        return new CompositeItemReader();
    }

    public ItemWriter<ReportMetadataDTO> reportMetadataWriter() {
        return new ReportMetadataWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener listener() {
        return new ReportMetadataCompletionListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }


}
```

This is the composite ItemReader that i've created -

```
    @Component
public class CompositeItemReader implements ItemReader<ReportMetadataDTO> {

    private ItemReader<String> recordReader;

    @Autowired
    private ReportMetadataService reportMetadataService;

    @Override
    public ReportMetadataDTO read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException,
            NonTransientResourceException {

        reportMetadataService.getReportMetada();
        /*if(recordReader == null) {
            recordReader = new IteratorItemReader<String>(getRecords());
        }*/
        ReportMetadataDTO data = new ReportMetadataDTO();
        //return recordReader.read();
        return data;
    }

}
```

This is the service I'd like to call which is Autowired in the ItemReader.

```
    @Service
public class ReportMetadataServiceImpl implements ReportMetadataService {

    @Autowired
    private ReportMetadataDao reportMetadataDao;

    @Override
    public void getReportMetada() {
        reportMetadataDao.getReportDetails();
    }

}
```

Edit -

Stack Trace -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.test.batch.jobs.ReportMetadata.step.CompositeItemReader.read(CompositeItemReader.java:40)
    at com.test.batch.jobs.ReportMetadata.step.CompositeItemReader.read(CompositeItemReader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.test.CustomReportWriterApplication.main(CustomReportWriterApplication.java:12)
```

Comment: It isn't a `@Bean`.

Comment: I tried creating Bean in the configuration file for the service but it still throws the same NPE. @Bean
 public ReportMetadataService reportMetadataService() {
  return new ReportMetadataServiceImpl();
 }

Comment: Please provide the stack trace

Comment: Since you mentioned that you are using Spring Boot, so have you configured DB settings in application.properties which is used in your DAO

Comment: @MichaelMinella - added the stack trace

Comment: @AmitKBist - this happens even before the DAO call. On any bean invocation.

Comment: @M.Deinum - you were right. I just couldn't see it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't wiring up your bean correctly.  You want to either use `@Component` on your class and let Spring create it or add `@Bean` on the factory method and you create it.  In this case, you have `@Component` so you're getting one instance that Spring knows about, but that's not the one that you're injecting into your `ItemReader`.  The one you're injecting into your `ItemReader` is a plain one that isn't autowired (since Spring doesn't know about it).  I'd recommend removing the `@Component` from your `CompositeItemReader` and adding `@Bean` to `public ItemReader<ReportMetadataDTO> compositeItemReader()`.

Comment: Did exactly that and it worked. My bad, didn't see that earlier. Thanks!